# Deleting a comment and associated images

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to delete single user comments and the pictures related with them, by deleting them from both the database records and storage. Unfortunately I keep getting errors.  Below is the code I have so far.

Tables: 
**Comments**: id, comment, user_id, person_id
**pictures**: id, image, comment_id, user_id, person_id

Relationships:
Comment:

```
public function pictures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Picture', 'comments_id', 'id');
}
```

pictures:

```
   public function comments()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment', 'comments_id');
    }
```

Controller:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $comment = Comment::find($id);
    Storage::delete($comment->pictures());

    $comment->delete();
    Session::flash('success', 'Your comment and pictures were deleted');

    return redirect()->route('home');
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: whats the error??

Comment: that it doesnt delete both the comment and the related images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `pluck()` to load images file names:

```
$files = $comment->pictures()->pluck('filename');
```

Then delete these files:

```
foreach ($files as $file) {
    Storage::delete(storage_path('images/' . $file));
}
```

This is just an example, you need to put correct column name instead of `filename` and build the correct path to the images.

To delete images from DB:

```
$comment->images()->delete();
```

Answer (score 2):

`$comment->pictures()` returns the definition of a relation, not the related pictures. if you want to delete all the pictures, you'll need to iterate through them and delete one by one:

```
$comment = Comment::find($id);
foreach ($comment->pictures as $picture) {
  // delete picture from storage
  Storage::delete($picture->id); //or whatever field is used as key in the storage
  // delete picture from the database - might be optional if you've set a cascade on delete behaviour in your foreign key definition
  $picture->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide `filename` of image to delete image from `storage`.

```
$comment = Comment::find($id);
foreach($comment->pictures as $picture)
        Storage::delete($picture->image);

Picture::where('comment_id',$comment->id)->delete();
$comment->delete();
```